# A2004 Problem With MASM32

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, masm32

I have a problem with the MASM32 assembler

The following code is a Hello World example that I copied from the MASM32 tutorial:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    message   db "Hello world!", "$"
.code

_main   proc

    mov   ax,seg message
    mov   ds,ax

    mov   ah,09
    lea   dx,message
    int   21h

    mov   ax,4c00h
    int   21h

_main   endp
end _main
```

On attempt to assemble, MASM32 throws A2004 error with the following comment:

```
C:\masm32\console.asm(11) : error A2004: symbol type conflict
```

Can anyone help me with that?
This code worked perfectly fine with the TASM assembler, but now I have to use MASM32 and I am having this A2004 error for any assembly code that I've earlier proven to work with TASM.

In case this is relevant, I am have a 32bit CPU running Win7 OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that `.model small` and `seg` are artefacts of an earlier age when the x86 architecture was truly segmented (into 64K chunks).

The `masm32` IDE doesn't like them very much at all (not unexpected since it's far more common nowadays to be doing 32-bit flat model code).

The problem lies in the fact that the `bin\assmbl.bat` file is being used by the editor to assemble the file and it contains the line:

```
\masm32\bin\ml /c /coff %1.asm > \masm32\bin\asmbl.txt
```

(with the `/coff` option). This is what's making the assembler complain.

You can get it to work by reverting to the command line. Assuming your file is `tst.asm`, use the following commands:

```
c:\masm32\bin\ml.exe /c tst.asm
c:\masm32\bin\link16 tst.obj.tst.exe,,,,
```

and you'll have a `tst.exe` that works fine.

---

The following transcript shows that this works:

```
C:\masm32> type tst.asm
.model small
.stack
.data
    message   db "Hello world!", "$"
.code

_main   proc

    mov   ax,seg message
    mov   ds,ax

    mov   ah,09
    lea   dx,message
    int   21h

    mov   ax,4c00h
    int   21h

_main   endp
end _main
```

```
C:\masm32> bin\ml.exe /c tst.asm
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: tst.asm
```

```
C:\masm32> bin\link16 tst.obj,tst.exe,,,,

Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993.  All rights reserved.
```

```
C:\masm32> tst.exe
Hello world!
```

---

Alternatively, the editor is very configurable. If you open up the `menus.ini` file for editing (back it up first, I shouldn't need to tell you that) and change:

```
&Assemble ASM file,\MASM32\BIN\Assmbl.bat "{b}"
```

to:

```
&Assemble ASM file,\MASM32\BIN\Assmbl.bat "{b}"
Assemble ASM file (no COFF),\MASM32\BIN\Assmbl2.bat "{b}"
```

you can get your new menu item added on IDE restart.

You also need to copy `bin\assmbl.bat` to `bin\assmbl2.bat` and remove the `/coff` from the latter.

Then you can compile fine from within the IDE with the new menu option.

Of course, you'll have to do the same thing for the `link` and `assemble/link` menu items as well. But, now that you know how it's done, that shouldn't present a problem.

Comment: I've eventially came up with a script to do the assemble/link commands. but thanks for the IDE tip, I didn't know that it is that flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used MASM - but isn't 'message' a reserved word?  try '_message'.