# Assembler Problem

Tags: assembly, masm

I have MASM assembler to "compile" 16 bit programs.
When I tried to "compile" my sample, the MASM throw me some errors:

```
error A2004: symbol type conflict
 warning A4023: with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address : START
```

my code is:

```
STA SEGMENT STACK
    DB 100H DUP(0)
STA ENDS

    CODE SEGMENT
        ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:CODE,SS:STA
    START:MOV AX,CODE
           MOV DS, AX
           MOV DX, OFFSET BOKER
           MOV AH, 8
           INT 21H
           MOV AX, 4C00H
           INT 21H
           BOKER DB 'Hello world!$'

    CODE ENDS
    END START
```

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever go around this? I'm facing the same issue `A2004`.

Answer (score 1):

The error literally says what's wrong... `warning A4023: with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address : START`

So change `START:MOV AX,CODE` to `_START:MOV AX,CODE`

And [A2004 Problem With MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747954/a2004-problem-with-masm32) here you can find a fix for the A2004 error

Comment: MASM throw another errors:
 error A2006: undefined symbol : START

Comment: Right now, MASM throwing another error:

     error A2006: undefined symbol : START
    error A2004: symbol type conflict
    error A2148: invalid symbol type in expression : START

please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
STA SEGMENT STACK
    DB 100H DUP(0)
STA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:CODE,SS:STA

_START:
    MOV  AX,CODE
    MOV  DS, AX
    MOV  DX, OFFSET BOKER
    MOV  AH, 8
    INT  21H
    MOV  AX, 4C00H
    INT  21H
    BOKER DB 'Hello world!$'

CODE ENDS
END _START
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you answer a question, it often is clearer to say what the problem is instead of just fixing it. Also, did you mean for a lot of those `STA SEGMENT etc` to be in code blocks? If so, put four spaces before the lines they are on, or encase them with the ` character.