# Getting an error: symbol type conflict in MASM when trying to run a program that takes in a char to return it's binary ascii code

Tags: c, assembly, masm, tasm, masm32

I am not sure why the program, when ran gives an assembly error that says:

> Desktop\MASM\test.asm(10) : error A2004: symbol type conflict

This program is supposed to be able to take in a character and output its respective ASCII code in binary. How can I make it so that this error is gone and I can run the program?

```
;Program takes in a character to output its' ASCII code in Binary
;and the number of 1 bit's in its ASCII code

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data  
      a db 0AH 

.code  
      mov      ax, @data      ; Initialize data section  
      mov      ds, ax  
      mov      al, a          ; Load number1 in al  
      mov      cl , 08H  
      mov      ah, 0h         ; ah=00  
up:     
      shl      al, 01h        ; divide the number by 2 and SHL gives the same result         
      mov      bl, al                 
      mov      al, 00H  
      adc      al, 30h  
      mov      dl, al  
      mov      ah, 02h  
      int      21h  
      mov      al,bl  
      dec      cl  
      jnz      up  
      mov      ah, 4cH        ; Terminate Program  
      int      21H  
end
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747954/a2004-problem-with-masm32 or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570140/assembler-problem

Comment: Same error after changing to eax